# How to examine memory for all registers at once with gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb, cpu-registers

In gdb, there is the `info registers` command, which prints the values inside the registers, and the `x/x reg` command, which treats the register as a pointer and prints whatever its value is pointing to in memory. Is there some way to do the `x/x reg` command for all registers at once? Like piping the output of `info registers` into it?

I saw that you can [make your own commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html), but it seems that the only solution there is to first manually type out all the registers. Is there a better way?

Comment: In most code, not all the registers are valid pointers (and others may be pointing near each other), so I'd be surprised if there was a single built-in command.  IDK enough about GDB's Python-based command language to know if there's a concise way to get a list of all register values and loop over them as pointers.

Comment: If you can make your own command, then please do. Your application seems very rare/improbable since at any given moment it's very rare that all registers would point to valid memory.

Comment: Looks like an http://xyproblem.info to me.

Comment: If you use the x command on a single register that doesn’t point anywhere it just says it doesn’t point anywhere. I was simply wondering if there were a command that did that for every register. Not sure how that’s the xy problem.

Answer (score 2):

For creating more complex command you should consider using GDB's Python API, details of which can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html).

To get you started, here's a first cut of a command that roughly does what you want:

```
class XXAll (gdb.Command):
  """Print every register as though it is a pointer."""

  def __init__(self):
    super(XXAll, self).__init__("xxall", gdb.COMMAND_USER)

  def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
      frame = gdb.selected_frame()
      arch = frame.architecture()
      for rd in arch.registers('general'):
        value = gdb.parse_and_eval(f"${rd}")
        type = value.type
        if type.code != gdb.TYPE_CODE_PTR:
            if type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_VOID:
                type = gdb.lookup_type('int').pointer()
            else:
                type = type.pointer()
        elif (type.target().code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_VOID
              or type.target().code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_FUNC):
            type = gdb.lookup_type('int').pointer()
        string = "%-10s" % str(rd)
        try:
            value = value.cast(type)
            value = value.dereference()
            string += value.format_string(format='x')
        except Exception as e:
            string += str(e)
        finally:
            print(string)

XXAll ()
```

Place the code into a file `xxall.py`, then within your GDB session:

```
  (gdb) source xxall.py
  (gdb) xxall
  ... lots of output ...
```

As others have pointed out in the comments, just treating every register as a pointer will usually not make sense, and you have to figure out things like, do I dereference based on the type of the register, or on some known fixed type.  Anyway, I handled some cases within the code to give you an idea for where to start, but most of these things will depend on your exact use case, so tweak the code as needed.

Final note: I'm not sure how many of these Python feature require a very recent version of GDB.  The Python API grows with each release.  I'm using GDB 11.1, so if the code below complains about missing functions, and you're using an older GDB - update!